# How to use the logical model in oracle sql developer on a mac?

Tags: macos, oracle-sqldeveloper, erd

For macs, the right-click doesn't work in the Oracle SQL Developer which makes making E-R diagrams impossible. I found someone's tip to double click "logical model" in "Browser" and then click "visible". This does open up the logical view and allow me to create entities and relations. The problem now is that because I can't right-click to open up properties I am unable to rename the entity and add attributes. Is there a way to get this working on Macs or do I need to find an HP to get this done.

If you need any more information let me know.

Comment: Have a look here https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mh35853/mac

Comment: @MarkSetchell my control-click works everywhere it just doesn't seem to work in the Oracle SQL developer

Comment: control click or right-click? and by control click, do you mean cmd click? to open properties for object in diagram, you just select it and right click or hit enter with your kb

Answer (score 0):

'right mouse does not work on macs'

Um, yes it does.

[image]

What version of Java are you running?

Do you see any messages on the Logging page (View - Log)? I imagine you will see a ton of messages where something is failing with your mouse.

Comment: I'm running java 8. I'm not getting any messages in the log that is saying my mouse is failing. I will say though I'm on a laptop not a desktop so I am using the trackpad.

Comment: Is the relational model different than the logical model? I was told to do this E-R Diagram assignment through the logical model view rather than the relational model.

Comment: but are you running ORACLE Java 8 JRE or JDK? Or is it openJDK? We don't support or test for openJDK 8 on macs. Also, what version of mac and what version of data modeler are you using?